# When is the transaction mined?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, blockchain, hash

I'm working on an ethereum blockchain project where people want to make reservations in a city. My backend sends a transaction to the smart contract with the user id, city and other data. The smart contract must perform other operations including communicating with an oracle. BookRequest (send) is called. This method calls the oracle smart contract. When the oracle smart contract (via its backend) gets the necessary data it calls the CallBack method. I have a doubt: when is the transaction mined? Before getting the final result (booking was successful or not)? Or later? If the transaction was mined and I received the hash, what does "Restore request context from Requests [id_]" mean? Are transactions not immutable?
The user wants to check if the booking was successful and uses the hash of the transaction, but what does he find? Find the booking result that was updated when it did the restore context? I do not know if I was clear.

```
function BookRequest(bytes32  id_, bytes32  location_, bytes32  attr1, int256  attr2) public payable
   {
       bool  result ;

        Requests[id_]=Request({ Location: location_, 
                                   Attr1: attr1,
                                   Attr2: attr2     }) ;

        (result,)=address(WeatherAddr).call.gas(0x300000).value(msg.value)(abi.encodeWithSignature("GetWetaher(bytes32,bytes32)", id_, location_)) ;
      if(result==false)  require(false) ;
   }

function CallBack(bytes32  id_, int256  tempirature_) public
   {
//          1. Restore request context from Requests[id_]
//          2. Process request for booking
   }
```

Comment: Transactions are mined when they are incorporated into a block. It is possible a chain reorganization will affect the ordering, so an oracle may wait for several confirmations blocks before answering a request.

Comment: Restore request seems to indicate that if you need some parameter from the request, like location_, you can retrieve from the mapping using the id_.